Question about probabilities from a binomial distribution and rolling dice
Obligatory apology if a similar question has been posted previously. Suppose I roll a standard 6-sided die $N$ times where $N$ is large. Let $X_k$, $k \in\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ denote the number of times a $k$ is rolled. I understand how to use a binomial distribution to answer questions like this: What is the probability that $X_1 \ge 100$? The binomial distribution just gives me $\sum_{i=100}^N {N\choose i}(1/6)^i(5/6)^{N-i}$. What I don't understand is how to get probabilities involving multiple of the $X_k$ variables. For example: what is the probability $X_1+X_2>\frac{X_3}{2} + X_4$? I intuitively understand that this probability should be large and should limit to 1 as $N\rightarrow \infty$ because each of the $X_k$ is approximately equal to the others; can I justify this using a binomial distribution? If so, how? Thank you.

I think this will use convergence rather binomial distributions. As N becomes large, the value of $\frac{X_i}{N}$ will converge to its probability, and hence you can take the expected value on both sides of the inequality.

The problem is that $X_1, \ldots, X_6$ are dependent. To see this, consider
\begin{align*}
P(X_1 = N, X_2 = N) = 0 \neq P(X_1 = N) \cdot P(X_2 = N)
\end{align*}
since if we have $N$ trials then we cannot observe both $1$ and $2$ exactly $N$ times. In order to find the probability you are asking for, you need the joint distribution, i.e. all terms of the form
\begin{align*}
P(X_1 = x_1, \ldots, X_6 = x_6)
\end{align*}
and use the discrete convolution to find e.g. the distribution of $X_1 + X_2$. I believe that this is very cumbersome and even in your example already hard to do. In practice, I would suggest to use a Monte Carlo simulation to estimate the desired probabilities (but I would be interested, if anyone really tries to write this down explicitly).

Thanks for the response. I was worried this would be the case, but you're probably right about Monte Carlo simulation.

$X_1+X_2$ is not difficult to deal with, as it has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $\frac13$.  But $\frac{X_3}{2} + X_4$ has a less simple distribution and its relationship with $X_1+X_2$ is complicated.

The comparison $X_1+X_2>\frac{X_3}{2} + X_4$ is equivalent to $$2X_1 + 2X_2 - X_3 - 2 X_4 > 0$$
In turn, this is equivalent to having a die with faces labeled 2, 2, -1, -2, 0, 0, and seeing whether the sum of $N$ rolls of the die is positive. By the central limit theorem this will converge to a normal distribution as $N \rightarrow \infty$, and as each roll has positive expected value, the number of standard deviations above zero of the mean will increase without bound. Therefore the probability of a positive result converges to 1.
Up to moderate $N$, the sum distribution can be computed via repeated convolution. Many dice probability calculators can do this in a single line, for example AnyDice:
output 100d{2,2,-1,-2,0,0} > 0


Cool thank you.

This answer provides an explicit formula for the probability that $~X_1 + X_2 > \dfrac{X_3}{2} + X_4,~$ as a function of $~N,~$ the number of die throws.
However, the closed form expression is so convoluted that I am unable to prove that the limit, as $~N \to \infty,~$ of this probability is $~1.$

For ease of syntax, this answer adopts the convention that when $~a < b,~$ the expression $~\displaystyle \binom{a}{b}~$ should evaluate to $~0.$
Assume that you have thrown the 6 sided die $~N~$ times.
In order for $~X_1 + X_2~$ to be greater than $~\dfrac{X_3}{2} + X_4,~$ you must have that $~X_1 + X_2~$ is some element $~r~$ in $~\{1,2,3,\cdots,N\}.~$
Assuming that there are $~N~$ die throws, for $~r \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}~:$

Let $~f(N,r)~$ denote the probability that $~(X_1 + X_2) = r.$

Let $~g(N,r)~$ denote the probability that $~\left( ~\dfrac{X_3}{2} + X_4 ~\right) < r,~$ given that $~X_1 + X_2 = r.~$


Then, the desired computation is
$$\sum_{r=1}^N \left[ ~f(N,r) \times g(N,r) ~\right]. \tag1$$
So, the entire problem reduces to computing $~f(N,r)~$ and $~g(N,r).$

For $~(X_1 + X_2)~$ to equal $~r,~$ two things must happen:

$X_1~$ must be some element in $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,r\}.$ 
Note that this is out of $~N~$ die throws.

Of the $~(N - X_1)~$ remaining die throws, $~X_2~$ must equal $~(r - X_1).$


The probability of this happening is
$$f(N,r) = \frac{4^{N - r}}{6^N} \times \sum_{X_1 = 0}^r \left[ ~\binom{N}{X_1} \times \binom{N - X_1}{r - X_1} ~\right]. \tag2 $$

To compute $~g(N,r),~$ you must first assume that $~X_1 + X_2 = r.~$
This implies that there are now $~(N-r)~$ die throws, each of which was some element in $~\{3,4,5,6\}.~$
Then, for $~\left( ~\dfrac{X_3}{2} + X_4 ~\right)~$ to be less than $~r,~$ two things must happen:

$X_4~$ must be some element in $~\{0,1,\cdots,r-1\}.~$

$\dfrac{X_3}{2}~$ must be less than or equal to $~(r - 1 - X_4).$ 
This will be true, if and only if $~X_3 \leq (2r - 2 - 2X_4).$


The probability of this happening is
$$g(N,r) = \sum_{X_4 = 0}^{r-1} \left\{ ~\binom{N-r}{X_4} \times \frac{3^{N - r - X_4}}{4^{N-r}} \times \\
\left[ ~\sum_{X_3 = 0}^{2r-2 - 2X_4}  \binom{N - r - X_4}{X_3} \times \frac{2^{N - r - X_4 - X_3}}{3^{N-r-X_4}} \right] 
~\right\}$$
$$= \frac{1}{4^{N-r}} \times \sum_{X_4 = 0}^{r-1} \left\{ ~\binom{N-r}{X_4} \times \\
\left[ ~\sum_{X_3 = 0}^{2r-2 - 2X_4}  \binom{N - r - X_4}{X_3} \times 2^{N - r - X_4 - X_3} ~\right] 
~\right\}. \tag3 $$

Combining the expressions in (2) above and (3) above gives
$$f(N,r) \times g(N,r)$$
$$= \frac{1}{6^N} \times \left\{ ~\sum_{X_1 = 0}^r \left[ ~\binom{N}{X_1} \times \binom{N - X_1}{r - X_1} ~\right] ~\right\} $$
$$\times \left\{ ~\sum_{X_4 = 0}^{r-1} \binom{N-r}{X_4} \times \\
\left[ ~\sum_{X_3 = 0}^{2r-2 - 2X_4}  \binom{N - r - X_4}{X_3} \times 2^{N - r - X_4 - X_3} ~\right] 
~\right\}.$$

Thank you for the response, this is extremely interesting.
